# Can you calculate p value without a standard deviation?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, p-value, standard-deviation

So, when you use it to analyse your website's speed, Google Analytics provides you with the mean loading time for your site's pages, along with the sample size used to calculate that mean. However, it does not provide you with the standard deviation or variance of the distribution.

Is it possible to calculate the p-value that changes to the mean page loading time represent genuine changes to your site's page loading time, rather than simply being random fluctuations? Could you do some sort of trick like turning the two month-long samples you're comparing into two sets 30 day-long samples to help with the lack of a standard deviation for any of these samples?

Is there some obscure statistical function I could call in r to handle this for me? I don't think that chi-squared would work because it's not count data, and I couldn't see anything else terribly relevant while looking through the help documentation of r's default stats library. Surely I'm not the first person to want to do statistical analysis of this Google Analytics data, right?

Comment: I don't have the time to elaborate this right now, but assuming independence and normality with a constant variance for every single time, I believe that if you have several means and sample sizes, you can reconstruct a variance estimator from the variation of the means, using the fact that every mean has variance $\sigma^2/n_i$ with $\sigma^2$ constant variance and $n_i$ sample size for that mean.

Comment: @ChristianHennig That's good to know. Do you know if there's an existing r function that can calculate this automatically?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Is there any relationship between mean and p-value?